# Undefined Reference to SDL functions

Tags: c++, sdl, codeblocks, sdl-2

I am trying to set up SDL 2.0.3 in CodeBlocks for almost two days with no luck so far. 
 
I am using latest version of Codeblocks, MinGW and SDL. 
 
I think I have properly included and linked all the SDL files from *lib* and *include* directories into  codeblocks by using `Settings/Compiler/Search Directories` in Codeblocks. 
I have also added following line into the Settings/Compiler/Linker Settings/Other Linker Options:

```
-lmingw32 -lSDL2main -lSDL2 -lSDL2_image -lSDL2_mixer
```

I have added SDL2.dll to the project directory.
I believe I am using right SDL files. I have 64 system and I am using files from *x86_64-w64-mingw32* directory. Which should be the right one for 64 system according to several tutorials on the web. 
 
(
When you download SDL development libraries there are version for both 32 and 64 systems so there are two directories: *x86_64-w64-mingw32* and *i686-w64-mingw32* Their names are quite misleading in my opinion)

I have this simple testing code:

```
#include <SDL.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    // Start SDL2
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING);

    // Create a Window in the middle of the screen
    SDL_Window *window = 0;

    window = SDL_CreateWindow("Hello World!",
                              SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED,
                              SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED,
                              640, 480,
                              SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);

    // Delay so that we can see the window appear
    SDL_Delay(2000);

    // Cleanup and Quit
    SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
    SDL_Quit();

    return 0;
} <br>
```

And I compiler says the following:

```
mingw32-g++.exe -LC:\SDL\SDL2_2.0.3\lib -LC:\SDL\SDL2_image_2.0.0\lib -LC:\SDL\SDL2_mixer_2.0.0\lib -o bin\Debug\Snake.exe obj\Debug\main.o  -lmingw32 -lSDL2main -lSDL2 -lSDL2_image -lSDL2_mixer  
obj\Debug\main.o: In function `SDL_main':
D:/CodeBlocks/Snake/main.cpp:6: undefined reference to `SDL_Init'
D:/CodeBlocks/Snake/main.cpp:15: undefined reference to `SDL_CreateWindow'
D:/CodeBlocks/Snake/main.cpp:18: undefined reference to `SDL_Delay'
D:/CodeBlocks/Snake/main.cpp:21: undefined reference to `SDL_DestroyWindow'
D:/CodeBlocks/Snake/main.cpp:22: undefined reference to `SDL_Quit'
c:/program files (x86)/codeblocks/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.7.1/../../../libmingw32.a(main.o):main.c:(.text.startup+0xa7): undefined reference to `WinMain@16'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I have followed this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wWGtuc5uqF4
Things have sligthly changed, because when you download SDL development library and unzip it. It looks different, but I believe I did it at least partialy right, because compiler can at found `<SDL.h>`

**I Know there are several same or familiar question, but none of them has accepted answer.**

I will appreciate every help.

Comment: Try `-m64` for 64 bit compilation.

Answer (score 1):

I realized, that the **[tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wWGtuc5uqF4)** I have mentioned before **was made for 32 bit version** so I tried to use 32 bit version and **everything is working now**. 
 
 Except that you need to obtain fixed version of `SDL_platform.h` file and replace the old one with him. This is a bug in SDL version 2.0.3 that should be fixed in newer versions according to what I have found on internet. 
 
 If you dont do that you will get compilation error saying something about `winapifamily.h`